# Original codes run well, but when I change to replace React.createElement by JSX, it seems not working, why?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm new using react and I'd like to convert from only react to JSX language.

The original codes run well, here are the original codes:

```
<script>

    class MyHead extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return React.createElement("LI", null, "ITEM" + this.props.level);
        }
    }

    class MyheadList extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { maxLevel: props.start };
        }

        componentWillMount() {
            this.intervalID = window.setInterval(() => {
                this.setState((currentState, currentProps) => {
                    if (currentState.maxLevel > currentProps.end) {
                        return currentState;
                    } else {
                        return { maxLevel: currentState.maxLevel + 1 }
                    }
                }
                );
            }, 1000);
        }

        componentWillUnount() {
            window.clearInterval(this.intervalID);
        }

        render() {
            let heads = [];
            let head;
            for (let i = 1; i < this.state.maxLevel; i++) {
                head = React.createElement(MyHead, { level: i });
                heads.push(head);
            }
            return React.createElement("UL", null, heads);
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        let reactElement = React.createElement(MyheadList, { start: 1, end: 4 });
        ReactDOM.render(
            reactElement, document.body
        );
    });
</script>
```

Those above codes run well, but when I change to replace React.createElement by JSX, it seems not the same logic outcome as the original codes, why ?

I only remove all React.createElement and use JSX syntax to replace it. Besides, all other codes are the same as the original one.

What codes I modify are like below:

```
<script type="text/babel">

    class MyHead extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return <li>"ITEM" {this.props.level}</li>;
        }
    }

    class MyheadList extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { maxLevel: props.start };
        }

        componentWillMount() {
            this.intervalID = window.setInterval(() => {
                this.setState((currentState, currentProps) => {
                    if (currentState.maxLevel > currentProps.end) {
                        return currentState;
                    } else {
                        return { maxLevel: currentState.maxLevel + 1 }
                    }
                });
            }, 1000);
        }

        componentWillUnount() {
            window.clearInterval(this.intervalID);
        }


        render() {
            let heads = [];
            let head;
            for (let i = 1; i < this.state.maxLevel; i++) {
                head = <MyHead level={i} />;
                heads.push(head);
            }
            return <ul>{heads}</ul>;
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        let reactElement = <MyheadList start="1" end="4" />;
        ReactDOM.render(
            reactElement, document.body
        );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What are the differences in outcome? Can you be more specific about what isn't working in your updated code? What version of React are you using?

Comment: @Drew Reese The version of React I'm using is:
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js">

The original code show ITEM1, ITEM2, ITEM3, ITEM4, one after the other per second, and then it will stop. So finally there should be only 4 ITEM(ITEM1~ITEM4) on the page.
But my updated code show ITEM1~ITEM10(total 10 ITEM) at the first second, and It will generate more ITEMxxx per second and never stops. It seems like in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

It seems the issue might've come down to string concatenation versus math, or the javascript types. The `start` and `end` props are string values, and when setting the initial `maxValue` state from props it retains the string type.

Later when comparing the current `maxLevel` state value to the `end` prop value it is a coincidence that the char values work out mathematically.

```js
console.log("1" < "2"); // true
console.log("2" < "1"); // false
console.log(1 < "2");   // true
console.log("2" < 1);   // false
```

The `maxLevel` was actually having `1` appended to it each "tick". Type coercion between number and string is a little funny, it results in concatenation instead of addition.

```js
console.log(1 + 1);     // 2
console.log("1" + 1);   // "11"
console.log(1 + "1");   // "11"
console.log("1" + "1"); // "11"
```

## Solution

Though I haven't quite made sense of it, converting `maxLevel` to a number type resolves the odd rendering result. I don't think it makes a huge difference in *this* code, `componentWillMount` has essentially been deprecated in React v16, preferring the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. Added a React key for the mapped array for completeness.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { maxLevel: Number(props.start) };
}
```

When comparing two values you should strive to do the comparison within the same type, so convert the `end` prop value to a number for comparison.

```
if (currentState.maxLevel > Number(currentProps.end)) {
```

```js
class MyHead extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <li>"ITEM" {this.props.level}</li>;
  }
}

class MyheadList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { maxLevel: Number(props.start) };
  }

  intervalID = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalID = window.setInterval(() => {
      this.setState((currentState, currentProps) => {
        if (currentState.maxLevel > Number(currentProps.end)) {
          return currentState;
        } else {
          return { maxLevel: currentState.maxLevel + 1 };
        }
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnount() {
    window.clearInterval(this.intervalID);
  }

  render() {
    const heads = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < this.state.maxLevel; i++) {
      heads.push(<MyHead level={i} key={i} />);
    }
    return <ul>{heads}</ul>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <MyheadList start="1" end="4" />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.7.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.7.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```